# Maximum number of notification integrations in cloud AZURE exceeded

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-pipe

it turns out that after we've created 10 notification integrations, we are unable to create more and getting following error. Is it a hard limit? Is it on snowflake's or is it on azure's side? Can it be changed?

> Maximum number of notification integrations in cloud AZURE exceeded.

Code:

```
create notification integration xxx
enabled = true
type = queue
notification_provider = azure_storage_queue
azure_storage_queue_primary_uri = 'https://xxx'
azure_tenant_id = 'xxx';
```

Comment: It might be the case that the limit is on Azure's side: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits But I have no clie which category should I refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reach out to Snowflake support. Have you created multiple queues for per storage account?

Comment: It turned out that there's soft limit of 10. Support increased it to max which is 25.